# Is there a way to enter multiple values in a field in ms access using a combo box in form?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am making a database to track the daily sales.
The problem is how to enter multiple items that are sold. A customer may buy one or more items.

I have made a table with list of items sold (tbl-items),  then used a combo box on form which uses tbl-items as row source. However I can select only one item. I also tried using Lookup Wizard, and selecting allows multiple values but it gives a check box of items which I really don't want to use as the list consists of around 50 items and there is no keyboard support (pressing 'B' on keyboard won't take me to items starting with B).

Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you for your attention on the matter.

Comment: You should display the sold items in a listbox or data grid view. Then, you must have two buttons "Add" and "Remove". "Add" open a new form, where you can search an item from a list (e.g. by entering a search term in a textbox that filters the list). When you click an "OK" button, the form closes and the selected item is added to the list in the first form.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? Since tbl-items is source for items - what table do you save selected items into? Strongly advise not to use multi-value field. Should have Orders and  OrderDetails tables. Can use a multi-select listbox then will need VBA to loop through selected items and save each to a separate record in OrderDetails. Otherwise, use a normal field and combobox to do data entry of one record at a time.

Comment: You should enter a separate row per sold item.